# Advice dealing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, exception, jboss, struts, nosuchmethoderror

Here is the error I am getting:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.Order.getList(Lepo/User;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
```

After decompiling the classes, I found that there should be a "Ljava/lang/String" as the first parameter.  As you can see by the error that parameter is missing.  So I decompiled the calling method's class and it does a have a string as the first parameter.

This is where I am a little confused to what is happening here.  The last time this code was modified was 2007 according to the timestamps.  This error showed up about a week ago.

This is a struts app running on JBoss 4.0.0DR3. To my knowledge there has been no software upgrades on the server.

I also tried stopping JBoss, deleting all the temp directories and restarting.

Does anyone have any suggestions to the next step to take?

Edit:

Here is more of the stacktrace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.Order.getList(Lepo/User;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/ArrayList;
    at com.ViewStatusAction.retrieveList(ViewStatusAction.java:325)
    at com.ViewStatusAction.executeAction(ViewStatusAction.java:115)
    at com.BaseAction.execute(BaseAction.java:42)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:484)
```

Comment: Did you check that the jar you decompiled and the jar that the code was compiled against is the same version?

Comment: Are you getting the "calling method's class" from the stacktrace, or what?

Comment: Yes the code that is decompiled is the same version as the running app.

Comment: Is it possible you removed another jar from the classpath, wherein that jar had the "same class", but a different version? That is, this "same class" was eclipsing the other, but once removed, the "incompatible class" in question manifested? This would be a classpath "race condition".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that both the `com.Order` and `com.ViewStatusAction` are application code, not 3rd-party code.

The exception means that you have a version mismatch of some kind.

- The `ViewStatusAction` class expects there to be a method in `Order` with this signature:

  ```
  java.util.ArrayList getList(Lepo.User arg0, 
                              String arg1, String arg2, 
                              String arg3, String arg4)
  ```
- The `Order` class does not declare a method with that signature.  (It may have a different signature, or it may not exist at all.)

When you originally compiled `ViewStatusAction`, the compiler was able to find that method.  However now, the runtime system cannot find it any more.  This can only mean that you are using a different version of `Order` to the one that your `ViewStatusAction` class was compiled against.

You need to find out why you've now got this mismatch.  Possible explanations include:

- You have deployed a new version of one of the classes without deploying the new version of the other.
- You have deployed an out of date version of one of the classes.
- You have two versions of one or other of the classes on your class path and you have unwittingly changed the classpath search order.

What you need to do is find out where the incompatible classes are coming from, and how they got there.  Once you have figured that out, the fix is likely to be self evident.

---

I note that your FQ class names doen't conform to accepted standards:

1. The package names should start with your organisation's domain name, reversed.  "com." is wrong.
2. The package names should be all lower-case.  "Lepo" is wrong if it is a package name, and if it is a class in the default package, then that is wrong too.

(It is possible that your problem might be a fall-out of fixing the bogus `Lepo.User` name ...)

Comment: I renamed the classes here. They are in a different namespace then i put here.

Comment: So, after digging around the JBoss deploy folder, I found that the classes got copied into another directory.  So, there was another class that was older that was being executed.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: *"I renamed the classes here. They are in a different namespace then i put here."* - In future, **DON'T DO THAT**.  It only confuses things if you tamper with the evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the runtime jar is different from the jar you use to compile your code. You may also have multiple jars on the classpath containing the same class and shadowing each other. You may want to check your app server runtime classpath, and the jar ordering.